# Haskell Function Type Signature in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

I have this Haskell function i'm trying to convert into Scala.

In Haskell you have a function like:

```
trifecta :: (a->b) -> (b->c) -> (c->d) -> a -> d
```

I haven't found anything online about converting these kinds of type signature in Scala.

This is what I have done so far, but I'm not quite sure this is correct.

Scala Code:

```
def trifecta[A,B,C,D](a: (A=>B), b: (B=>C), c: (C=>D), d: A): D = { 

    trifecta(a, b, c, d)
}
```

I'd really appreciate if you guys could help me clarify this. Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your types are fine but your implementation won't terminate. You probably meant:

```
def trifecta[A,B,C,D](a: A=>B, b: B=>C, c: C=>D, d: A): D = c(b(a(d)))
```

if you want it to be curried like the Haskell version you need separate argument lists:

```
def trifecta[A,B,C,D](a: A=>B)(b: B=>C)(c: C=>D)(d: A): D = c(b(a(d)))
```

Comment: Let's say I want to execute the code with `trifecta ( (+1), (+3), (+4), 8)`. Why do I get errors? I want the function to take three functions and a variable.

Comment: @rribeiro - Scala doesn't support sections like `+1` in Haskell. You can supply functions but the type checker can't infer the argument types without any surrounding context. You can do `trifecta((i: Int) => i+1, (i: Int) => i+3, (i: Int) => i+4, 8)`

Comment: `trifecta[Int, Int, Int, Int](_ + 1, _ + 3, _ + 4, 8)` would also do. Just have to hint the compiler what the types will be